# Yesod.Auth no authentication and no authorization

Tags: authentication, haskell, yesod

I'am writing a web app for personal use with Yesod. I don't want authentication and no log in.
What is the best way to achieve this?

- remove the Auth library from the application
- use a default hidden user that automatically logs in at startup (Auth.dummy?)
- or something else....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a recent version of the scaffolded site, you should be able to look in `src/Foundation.hs` for the definition of `isAuthorized`.  Replace the entire definition with:

```
isAuthorized _ _ = return Authorized
```

or even remove it entirely, since the above definition is the default.

That should be sufficient to allow access to all pages.  Next, search your code for uses of `maybeAuth*` and `requireAuth*` functions.  Make sure that pages that use `maybeAuth*` work as expected if they get back `Nothing`.  Remove any uses of `requireAuth*` and any dependencies on its return value.

Afterwards, you can clean up unneeded code, but this is entirely optional:

- In `Foundation.hs`, you can:

  - remove `Yesod.Auth.Dummy` and `Yesod.Auth.OpenId` imports
  - remove the definition of `muser <- maybeAuthPair` from `defaultLayout`
  - remove login/logout/profile pages from the navbar (`menuItems`)
  - remove the `authRoute` definition in the `instance Yesod App`
  - remove `AuthR` and `ProfileR` from the `breadcrumb`
  - remove the `instance YesodAuth App`, the definition of `isAuthenticated`, and the `instance YesodAuthPersist App`
- In `NoFoundation.hs`, you can remove the `Yesod.Auth` import.
- In `Settings.hs`, remove the `appAuthDummyLogin` field and the reference to it in `instance FromJSON AppSettings`
- In `config/routes.yesodroutes` remove `/auth` and `/profile` routes
- Remove `src/Handler/Profile.hs` and the `import Handler.Profile` from `Application.hs`.
- Stamp out any remaining references to `maybeAuth*` functions or references to the `ProfileR` route.